# Wine: <directory> not owned by you, refusing to create a configuration directory there

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I am trying to create a wineprefix so that I can install IL-2 1946 on my Ubuntu OS. I m using this resource: http://blogs.bu.edu/mhirsch/2012/07/making-wineprefixes-and-using-wineprefixes-wine-1-5/

The directory I am trying to create the prefix in is ~/games/Il-2_1946 but when I enter:

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/games/IL-2_1946/.wine_il-2 winecfg
```

I get the following error:

```
wine: '/home/promitheas/games/IL-2_1946' is not owned by you, refusing to create a configuration directory there
```

I have searched far and wide for a few hours now, but the closest thread I found relative to my issue was this one: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-634075.html

I also already have a wineprefix for Star Wars The Old Republic, and when I run the IL-2 setup.exe with wine I get this error:

```
wine: chdir to /home/promitheas/games/swtor/drive_c/Program Files/Electronic Arts/BioWare/Star Wars - The Old Republic/wineprefix
```

: No such file or directory

Furthermore, the game is from a mounted .iso file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same error while trying to create WINEPREFIX in gentoo x64. What i did:

```
$ rm ~username/.wine
$ WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/path/to/wineprefix winecfg
```

Attention: do not manually create the directory before running that command; Wine must create it. If you manually create the directory before running you will get message:

```
$ wine: WINEARCH set to win32, but '/path/to/wineprefix' is a 64-bit installation.
```

Comment: `sudo mkdir ~username/.wine` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to superuser mode and then type winecfg.
For example,

```
$ sudo su

# winecfg
```

Comment: Never run `wine` programs with super user privileges.